# C# WebClient unable to download csv file from link

Tags: c#, .net-core, webclient

Here is my code tries to download the csv file from mentioned url but getting and error.

```
string remoteUri = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-corporateActions?index=equities&from_date=30-07-2020&to_date=06-08-2020&csv=true";

string fileName = @"C:\test.csv";

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri,fileName);
```

Getting an error Fatal Error: Execution time limit was exceeded.
But hitting the above url in browser downloads the csv file

Answer (score 1):

This is because the HTTP server is expecting the following headers in your request:

```
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

You can try them in another REST client. I've been able to reproduce your problem with [ARC](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/install).

Answer (score -1):

There are some issues in that URL from where you are trying to get CSV file.I checked Your code with other CSV URL Its working fine. Bellow is the test CSV URL.

```
string remoteUri = "http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv";
    
                string fileName = @"Y:\Users Data\Sagar\Test\test.csv";
    
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                myWebClient.Headers.Add("contentType", "text/csv");
                await myWebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(remoteUri, fileName);
```